# How to construct an array of arrays from Resultset

Tags: java

I am working on Google charts API and 
Google Visualization Candlestick Charts expects data to be an array of arrays for it to work .

For example the below format

```
[
[ "2011-08-01", 136.65, 136.96, 134.15, 136.49 ],
[ "2011-08-02", 135.26, 135.95, 131.50, 131.85 ],
[ "2011-08-05", 132.90, 135.27, 128.30, 135.25 ]
]
```

This is my SQL by which i am retrieving the data from database

```
String selectsql = "select current_day ,  open_val , high_val , low_val , close_val  from   historical_data where symbol_name = ?";
while(Rset.next())
            {
                String current_day =  SgxRset.getString("current_day");
                String open_val =  SgxRset.getString("open_val");
                String high_val =  SgxRset.getString("high_val");
                String low_val =  SgxRset.getString("low_val");
                String close_val =  SgxRset.getString("close_val");
            }
```

Could you please tell me how to construct  how   to construct an array of arrays ??

sample program

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;

public class TestJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.setName("Ravi");
        emp1.setName("20");
        Employee emp2 = new Employee();
        emp2.setName("Kiran");
        emp2.setName("20");
        List<Employee> histList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

         Object[] arrayResultData = histList.toArray();

    }
}


public class Employee {

    String name ;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    String age ;

}
```

Comment: what about using a multidimensional array?

Comment: I don't think this is an array of array. It has one string and others are float values.

Comment: You don't want an array of arrays if you don't know how many rows you will have, because you can't resize the array - you'd need an array list of arrays, or something similar.

Comment: What have you tried? What part are you stuck on? Return a JSON array of arrays, creating a data structure in Java? Something else?

Comment: creating a data structure in Java

Comment: You did not add the emp1/2 to your list.   histList.add(emp1); histList.add(emp2);

Comment: okay but i added it but its printing in form of an object , i want it to be an array of data .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class which will held all these data together in an object like this with getters and setters:

```
 public class Data {
            private String current_day;
    private double open_val;
    private double high_val;
    private double low_val;
    private double close_val;

    public Data(String current_day, double open_val, double high_val,
            double low_val, double close_val) {
        this.current_day = current_day;
        this.open_val = open_val;
        this.high_val = high_val;
        this.low_val = low_val;
        this.close_val = close_val;
    }

    public String getCurrent_day() {
        return current_day;
    }

    public void setCurrent_day(String current_day) {
        this.current_day = current_day;
    }

    public double getOpen_val() {
        return open_val;
    }

    public void setOpen_val(double open_val) {
        this.open_val = open_val;
    }

    public double getHigh_val() {
        return high_val;
    }

    public void setHigh_val(double high_val) {
        this.high_val = high_val;
    }

    public double getLow_day() {
        return low_val;
    }

    public void setLow_day(double low_day) {
        this.low_val = low_day;
    }

    public double getClose_day() {
        return close_val;
    }

    public void setClose_day(double close_day) {
        this.close_val = close_day;
    }

    }
```

Now, store the data in array of objects which you are getting from SQL.

```
String selectsql = "select current_day ,  open_val , high_val , low_val ,close_val  from   historical_data where symbol_name = ?";
    List<Data> myList = new ArrayList(Data); 
    while(Rset.next())
                {
                    String current_day =  SgxRset.getString("current_day");
                    String open_val =  SgxRset.getString("open_val");
                    String high_val =  SgxRset.getString("high_val");
                    String low_val =  SgxRset.getString("low_val");
                    String close_val =  SgxRset.getString("close_val");

                    Data data = new Data(current_day,open_val,high_val,low_val,close_val);
                    myList.add(data);
                }
```

For reading data, you can write:

```
 String a = "[ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        String b = "[ \"" + myList.get(i).getCurrent_day() + "\" , "
                + myList.get(i).getOpen_val() + "],";
        if(i==myList.size() -1)
            a += b;
        else
            a += b+",";
    }
    a += " ]";
```

Now, for me the output is:

```
[ [ "2011-08-01" , 136.65],[ "2011-08-02" , 135.26] ]
```

Comment: thanks but its same thing know what erguant has mentioned ?? how is it different ??

Comment: Yeah, it is same, but, while I was writing the answer, some one has already answered.

Comment: I think, for creating an array of arrays is a illution here. You need to create a string which looks like an array of arrays. I have personally worked in google visualization. I think the edited code above will help you.

Comment: Thanks! Please let me know what happens!

Comment: It created an empty array [  ]

Comment: you can try from the sample code i have it my question (edited part)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94341/discussion-between-javaprogrammer-and-preethi-jain).

Comment: Changed the code. Please check again. There was a minor mistake. :) . Please let me know if this is working for you.

Comment: thank you but when i ran the program i am getting output as [ [ "20" , Ravi],,[ "20" , Kiran], ]

Comment: :( . But I have changed a minute back... For me, it is working fine. I have ran the code. And, provided the output as well. Please check again. I think there is some miscommunication. I have used the sample data : Data data1 = new Data("2011-08-01", 136.65, 136.96, 134.15, 136.49); First parameter is String, rest all are doubles.

Comment: Please check all the changes, in all the code sections. speciallly the last part where the if else condition is :  if(i==myList.size() -1)
            a += b;
        else
            a += b+",";

Comment: ya , got it thank you very much for your patience to help .

Comment: Thank you no problem... Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a List.  You don't know what your columns are and how many you have:

```
List<HistData> histList = new ArrayList<HistData>();
//.. query db
while(Rset.next()){
  HistData histData = new HistData();
  histData.setCurrentDay( SgxRset.getString("current_day"));
  histData.setOpenVal( SgxRset.getString("open_val"));
  histData.setHighVal( SgxRset.getString("high_val"));
  histData.setLowVal( SgxRset.getString("low_val"));
  histData.setCloseVal( SgxRset.getString("close_val"));
  histList.add(histData);
}
```

HistData is just a [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object), but you can change the datatypes in the bean and the SgxRset retrieval type, so you are not locked in to any array type.  Using a List as opposed to an array provides more flexibility in case you are returning many results of unknown length.

```
public class HistData {
    public HistData(){}
    String currentDay;
    public setCurrentDay(String currentDay){
        this.currentDay = currentDay;
    }
    public getCurrentDay(){
        return currentDay;
    }
    // .. etc.
}
```

Comment: but still how to construct such type of array from List ??

Comment: please see my edited part of my question i have created a sample part , how can i display that in form of what google charts expect ??

Answer (score 1):

Use a List and the toArray Method

```
String selectsql = "select current_day ,  open_val , high_val , low_val ,     close_val  from   historical_data where symbol_name = ?";

      List<String[]>resultData = new ArrayList<Stirng[]>();

        while(Rset.next())
                {
                    String[] array = new String[5];

                    array[0] =  SgxRset.getString("current_day");
                    array[1] =  SgxRset.getString("open_val");
                    array[2] =  SgxRset.getString("high_val");
                    array[3] =  SgxRset.getString("low_val");
                    array[4] =  SgxRset.getString("close_val");
                }

        Object[] arrayResultData = resultData.toArray();
```